# Need to map certain fields from the log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I received an exercise: I have a log examples
"Critical Machine_5 I have a really severe issue 42"
"Medium Machine_3 everything is fine 244"

I need to apply Grok patterns in order to map 4 fields "severity", "server" , "text" , "latency"

I am not a specialist in this field, but as I understood the logs should be transformed into the following:

```
 severity: Critical / Medium,
 server: Machine_5 / Machine_3,
 text: I have a really severe issue / everything is fine,
 latency: 42 / 244
```

The following code returns "Critical" for the first log. But doesn't work for the second.

```
%{LOGLEVEL:severity}
```

I use Grok debugger in order to check the approaches.
I know this is not a 5 min conversation. But could you help me to solve the issue and to understand the general idea?

Comment: The grok pattern `LOGLEVEL` works for standard log levels as the ones used by log4j or syslog for example, INFO, WARNING, CRITICAL, ERROR etc, Medium is not a log level, that's why your grok didn't work, change it to `%{WORD:severity}` and try again.

Comment: yes, finally solved: %{WORD:severity} %{WORD:server} %{GREEDYDATA:text} %{WORD:latency}

Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin It's ok to post your comment as an answer to the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to define the correct patterns, as @leandrojmp advised in comments.

Solution:
%{WORD:severity} %{WORD:server} %{GREEDYDATA:text} %{WORD:latency}